# xgettext fails to extract tag attributes

Tags: python, jinja2, bottle, python-babel, xgettext

I'm stuck with `xgettext` missing tag attributes in HTML templates, e.g.:

```
xgettext --keyword=_ --language=Python -o - - <<EOF
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    % msg = _('A translatable string')
    <title>{{ _('Page title') }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" title="{{ _('title') }}">_('Link text')</a>
  </body>
</html>
EOF
```

returns

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2021-10-20 11:52+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=CHARSET\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: standard input:4
msgid "A translatable string"
msgstr ""

#: standard input:5
msgid "Page title"
msgstr ""

#: standard input:8
msgid "Link text"
msgstr ""
```

where `a`'s `title` attribute is skipped.

FWIW, the template language is Python `bottle`'s [SimpleTemplate Engine](https://bottlepy.org/docs/0.12/stpl.html) which is incompatible with standard [`pybabel`](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/).

(To tell the truth you'll get the same result -- i.e. tag attributes ignored -- using `pybabel`'s javascript extractor, which I would rather use with the following `babel.cfg`)

```
[python: **/**.py]
[javascript: views/**.html]
```

Other tentative I did: use Jinja2 extractors which are incompatible with SimpleTemplate Engine's template inheritance syntax `{{!base}}`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up hacking [`jinja2.Environment`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#jinja2.Environment) initialization so to consider the `{{!base}}` command a comment.

```
[python: **/**.py]
[jinja2: views/**.html]
comment_start_string = {{!
comment_end_string = }}
silent=False
```

This way it won't find any translations in escaped prints — that's what `{{! ... }}` is for in SimpleTemplate Engine, should be a rare case you want to escape a translation text.

Also translations in python `%` and `<% ... %>` are somehow skipped, I haven't found a fix yet.